# How to get the absolute path of "pom.xml" from a jar file dependencie

Tags: java, maven

I'm referencing maven application jar number 1 inside another application jar number 2.
I run the jar number 2, I try to display the version of the application jar number 1,  but it displays the exception `FileNotFoundException: "pom.xml".`

How can I get the absolute or relative path of the `pom.xml` of the referenced jar ? Thank you

```
MavenXpp3Reader mavenReader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
Model mavenModel = mavenReader.read(new FileReader("pom.xml"));
String clientVersion = mavenModel.getVersion();
```

java.io.FileNotFoundException: pom.xml (Le fichier sp├®cifi├® est introuvable)

when i export the appli as a war file i found the file in this location: "groupeId"\META-INF\maven\"artifactId"\"appName"\pom.xml

Maybe if i read the groupeId and artifactId i could construct the correct path of the pom.xml ?

Comment: Consider the use of [getResourceAsStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String))

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work neither, the same error (i added above, the generated exception)

Comment: If you are inside an application you have to use getResourceAsStream()..with the correct location...and why do you need it?

Comment: Why i need it: I load the pom.xml to read the version of the referenced jar (jar number 1). That means that in the pom.xml of my running application (jar number 2) i have a referenced jar (jar number 1), then i need to read its version.

Comment: If you use getResourceAsStream() you must specify it exactly like in the method 'If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.
Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:
modified_package_name/name
Where the modified_package_name is the package name of this object with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').'

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Thank you for youe responses, i resolved this problem by using a propertie file:
application.name=@project.artifactId@
application.version=@project.version@
application.parent.version=@project.parent.version@